# I keep getting error 0xc8007000D On my Mac so i tried install windows by using cmd, but no results

Tags: mac, windows, bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2009) with macOS Mojave operating system. I want a dual boot with Windows 10 Pro. I am trying to install Windows directly on hardware, after using Unetbootin to make it bootable.

After using Unetbootin  to copy the `Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso` file to my flash drive, I booted up my MacBook Pro machine to install Windows 10. When I enter the

```
dism /apply-image /imagefile:d:\sources\install.wim /name:"Windows 10 Pro" /applydir:c:\ /checkintegrity
```

command, I received an error message, which is partially given below.

```
Error 13 

The data is invalid.

The DISM log file can be found at bla bla bla
```

Can someone tell me what the heck I am doing wrong, because I followed a lot of tutorial step by step and still don't know what happened?

[image]

Comment: You can't just copy an ISO to a USB drive and have it able to be bootable.  Are you trying to install Windows through Bootcamp or are you just trying to install it directly onto the hardware?

Comment: im trying to install windows directly on hardware, after using Unetbootin to make it bootable

Comment: Use bootcamp to create a bootable USB installer with the necessary drivers and once you are installing windows with bootcamp delete the macOS partition. That it if you don't want macOS on your Mac and only Windows.

Comment: I have answered many questions over the years regarding installing Windows on Intel Macs. Before suggesting a previous posted answer or posting a new answer, I think I would need to know at least the following. 1) What is the model year of your MacBook Pro? 2) Are you trying to install Windows as the only operating system or are do you want a macOS/Windows dual boot? 3) If dual boot, what version of macOS do you have installed? 4) What is the full name of the Windows ISO you downloaded from Microsoft. 5) Have you considered installing Windows 11?

Comment: hi, david anderson, i have a MacBook Pro 17 mid 2009 with macOS mojave operating system, and i want a dual boot, the name of the win10 iso is "Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso. no i don't considering installing win11

Answer (score 0):

I used the Disk Utility to erase a flash drive. I selected the "MS-DOS (FAT)" format and "Master Boot Record" scheme. Next, I used Unetbootin to transfer the `Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso` file to the flash drive. The `install.wim` file contained in the `Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso` file is 5.18 GB in size. However the `install.wim` file on the flash drive is only 4.29 GB in size, which is about the maximum size for a file stored in a FAT32 volume. I assume here that Unetbootin truncated the `install.wim` file without generating any type of error message. If the same occured for you, then you should get the error messages described in your question.

---

### One Possible Fix

1. Boot to macOS.
2. Use the Disk Utility to erase the volume where Windows is to be installer. I used "BOOTCAMP" for the name and "ExFAT" for the format.
3. Mount the `Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso` file.
4. Copy the `install.wim` file from the `sources` volume on the `CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9` volume to the `BOOTCAMP` volume.
5. Boot from the flash drive and open a Command Prompt window.
6. Enter the command given below.

   ```
   dism /split-image /imagefile:c:\install.wim /swmfile:d:\sources\install.swm /filesize:3072 /checkintegrity
   ```
7. Enter the command given below to format drive `C:` as NTFS.

   ```
   format c: /v:BOOTCAMP /q
   ```

Note that the `dism` command given in the OP's question would change to the command given below.

```
dism /apply-image /imagefile:d:\sources\install.swm /swmfile:d:\sources\install*.swm /name:"Windows 10 Pro" /applydir:c:\ /checkintegrity
```